# Overriding Magento 2 static adminhtml backend isn't working

Tags: magento2, backend, html, static-content, static-content-deploy

I've got file :

> "vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/templates/grid/listing.html"

after deploy this file create:

> "pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/templates/grid/listing.html"

I want edit this file but there is problem when i create:

> "app/design/adminhtml/{..}/{..}/Magento_Ui/web/templates/grid/listing.html"

after deploy file in static/adminhtml not change (still this file is same to vendor file).

Is there any other way to override this file or maybe i creating wrong path?

Comment: Delete the content and then deploy. It will work.

Comment: Why are you creating the file in app/design/frontend folder?

Comment: After delete content still is created file from "vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/templates/grid/listing.html"

Comment: @MohitKumarArora Because after create file in adminhtml havent any action.

Answer (score 1):

try below code it will override `listing.html`

Create `requirejs-config.js` under `Vendor/ModuleName/view/adminhtml` with following code.

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        'ui/template/grid/listing.html':'Vendor_ModuleName/template/grid/new-listing.html'
    }
}
```

};

and create `new-listing.html` file under `Vendor/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/web/template/grid` with your changes and
after that fire following command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Answer (score 1):

To override file of admin theme, You can create your own admin theme by making parent theme as a magento default admin theme (Magento/backend).

Follow below tutorial for create your own admin theme.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_create.html